# windows 10 clear type is enabled but font not displaying correctly

Tags: windows-10, display, fonts

I have HP Star War edition laptop which has IPS Full HD screen. I have latest drivers and updates for Windows 10 but in some apps fonts are not showing correctly. As you can see in screenshot, all link button is not at all displaying. Windows title is coming smoothly but menu items are a bit blurry. Same thing I noticed in Device Manager tree view, text are a bit blurry. Any idea how I can fix it.

[image: Highlighted areas where font is not showing correctly]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to start and type in: scaling. Go there  and set the scaling and restart the pc. Change few times and everything should be OK.

If this is a laptop using docking station,  please undock it first.

Comment: changing DPI setting to 100% from 125% fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the screen resolution is set to the default resolution for the laptop screen, and make sure that the scaling is set to the default, which is 100% .